# Execute method on enter key VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify and trying to create a method to add chips from the dropdown. Now i got most of the logic down but as you can see, the method `multipleSelection` does not fire off on the `enter` key but works fine `onClick`. 
Here is a demo for the [codepen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/Jjddrmr). 
So the method `multipleSelection` should fire off on the `enter key`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      arr: [],
      items: [{
          text: 'Foo',
          value: 'foo'
        },
        {
          text: 'Bar',
          value: 'bar'
        },
        {
          text: 'biz',
          value: 'buzz'
        },
        {
          text: 'buzz',
          value: 'buzz'
        }
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    multipleSelection(item) {
      this.arr.push(item)
      console.log(this.arr)
    },
    deleteChip(item) {
      console.log('delete')
      this.arr = this.arr.filter(x => x !== item);
      console.log(this.arr)
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-combobox :items="items" label="Add Multiple Chips" multiple small-chips solo deletable-chips :value="arr">
        <template v-slot:item="{ index, item }">
      <v-list-tile-content @click.stop.prevent="multipleSelection(item)">
        {{item.text}}
      </v-list-tile-content>
    </template>
        <template v-slot:selection="{ index, item }">
      <v-chip close dark color="info" @click:close="deleteChip(item)">
        {{ item.text }}
      </v-chip> 
    </template>
      </v-combobox>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You're confusing a `hover` state and a `selection`. They just have the same CSS. When you hover over an item you cannot interact with it directly because you haven't selected anything. When you use the `arrow` keys to navigate between items and press 'enter' it works fine to toggle it. This is the material design.

Comment: So when i click `enter` why doesn't the console.log appear?

Comment: Because `@click.stop.prevent` is not `@keypress.enter.prevent`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy `@keypress.enter.prevent` doesn't seem to fire off that method or even work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `multipleSelection()` is not being called from `@keypress` on `v-slot:item`, likely it's not where the event is being captured.

Taking a look at events on Vue Dev Tools, can see `input $emit by <VCombobox>` is the first one after pressing Enter.

So the following will get it, but this seems to mess with the position in the list for some reason I don't understand.

```html
<v-combobox
  ...
  @input.capture="(item) => multipleSelection(item)"
>
```

Better to add a listener,

```js
mounted() {
  this.$refs.combobox.$on('input', (items) => {
    const item = items[items.length -1];  // getting all selected, so take the last
    this.multipleSelection(item)
  })
},
```

Note, I tested this on a local project with Vuetify v1.5.14.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need @keyup

```
<v-list-tile-content 
@keyup.enter.prevent="multipleSelection(item)" @click.stop.prevent="multipleSelection(item)">{{item.text}}
</v-list-tile-content>
```

Not sure about keypress....Vue docs show @keyup

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Key-Modifiers